# I installed llama_index and did OpenAI certification, and it was working well The following error has occurred all of a sudden over the past few days

Tags: llama-index

I installed llama_index and did OpenAI certification, and it was working well
The following error has occurred all of a sudden over the past few days.

Is it a problem that was not done with the update between llama_index and OpenAI? I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

from llama_index.llms import OpenAI
from llama_index import VectorStoreIndex, SimpleDirectoryReader
from IPython.display import Markdown, display

> > ImportError: cannot import name 'OpenAI' from 'llama_index.llms' (unknown location)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue.
try this, as latest version of llama_index is `0.10.13`

`from llama_index.llms.openai import OpenAI`
`from llama_index.core import VectorStoreIndex, SimpleDirectoryReader`
`from IPython.display import Markdown, display`